# Why do I get question marks when I print a PChar to the console?

Tags: delphi, console

I have the following function in my application:

```
function GetDeviceChannelInfo_HSI(PortNumber, Address, ChNumber: Integer;
  var State: Integer): PChar; stdcall; external DLL_FILENEAME;
```

All I want to do is print the result of this to the console. What happens though, is that when I call a `WriteLn` on it, all i get is `???????????` as the response.

I am assuming that the console doesn't know how to print this. Perhaps it's Unicode or something and it can't be printed?

I am new to Delphi, and really have no idea why this could be. Am I actually printing the pointer address? I really don't know. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the function declaration is correct? Most DLL calls ask you to provide a buffer that they fill; you allocate the buffer, pass it in, and on return the buffer is filled with the DLL information. Returning a PChar is very unusual, because the DLL would allocate the memory and return the pointer to it to the calling application, which has no way to free it (unless they're both compiled in Delphi/C++ Builder and are using `ShareMem`). Where did you get the declaration you're using?

Comment: Change the PChar to PAnsiChar, and the problem goes away. Isn't this a duplicate, of about 30 other questions from people who didn't grok the Ansi to Unicode delphi types (`PChar` used to mean `PAnsiChar`, and now it means `PWideChar`)

Answer (score 3):

You're not printing the pointer address. If you were, you'd get something that looks like an address (a decimal or hexadecimal number), not question marks.

As of Delphi 2009, `PChar` is a pointer to Unicode characters. If you're using that version or later, make sure that that's what your function really returns. It's more likely the function returns a pointer to non-Unicode characters — that's what it would return if you translated this from C code where the function returned `char*`. The correct Delphi translation for that type is `PAnsiChar`.

When you print wide characters that aren't real characters, or that don't have representations in the current font, then you often get question marks.

If you're using an earlier Delphi version, and the function really does return `PWideChar` (`wchar_t*`, in C), then you could get the opposite problem, printing narrow characters when the function gave you wide characters. That's unlikely, though, because the wide characters you receive are problem just ASCII anyway, so your program would stop after printing the first one and encountering the nul byte that makes up the second half of the wide character.

You can use the debugger to give yourself an idea of what you really have. Take the address the function gives you and visit that address in the memory browser (part of the CPU view). You can have Delphi display the memory in different formats, including characters, wide characters, and numbers of various widths. It also helps if you have some idea of what result you're supposed to get. Then you might recognize patterns in the memory.

Answer (score 1):

Well you might have to post more code if this is wrong but I'd have expected some thing like

```
Var
  FuncResult : String;
Begin
  FuncResult := GetDeviceChannelInfo( ...);
  WriteLn(FuncResult);
End;
```

to work.

Basically just force some implict casts from PChar to String;

Comment: Thanks for the response. I gave this a try. When doing this, the result is an empty string instead of the ??????????. Not sure why this happened

Comment: Suggests while this function might be returning PChar, a PChar to what is an unknown. Have to decode the result to figure out what should be done with it.